# Scanning word phrases (user input) in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that can respond to commands and such (much like and AI) but I am having a problem with a part.

Here is what I have:

```
@echo off
set /p Quest="How are you today? "
echo %Quest% > Results.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims= " %%a in (Results.txt) do (
if %%(something)==good do "My day is doing good as well."
)
pause
```

How do I scan the contents of `Results.txt`?

For example: What if the user said: "I am good today" or simply "good." And since their response would be printed into `Results.txt` how could I simply scan for the word "good" (or any other descriptive adjective) only and respond to the user based on that one word (or any other descriptive adjective)?

Comment: You might find [this answer useful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28823049/1683264).  Basically, instead of echoing out to Results.txt, test `%Quest%` for the existence of good, fine, excellent, great, not bad, etc. either using `findstr` or substring substitution.  In this case, `findstr` might be preferable, as you can combine many synonyms in one command.  `echo(%Quest% | findstr /i "good great fine excellent" >NUL && (echo My day is going well, too.) || (echo Aww, I'm sorry to hear that.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Rojo suggests, there is no need to use a file and [`FINDSTR`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) command is what you are looking for for what you try to do. But to avoid weird results, like "not very well" interpreted as "well" and give you a better control on answers provided, I suggest to use regular expression (parameter `/r`). Something like this :

```
@echo off
set /p Quest="How are you today? "
echo %Quest% | findstr /r /i "not.*good not.*well" >nul && echo Sorry && goto:pause
echo %Quest% | findstr /i "good well" >nul && echo My day is doing good as well
:pause
pause
```

If you really want to go with a file try this way :

```
@echo off
set /p Quest="How are you today? "
echo %Quest% > Results.txt
findstr /r /i "not.*good not.*well" Results.txt >nul && echo Sorry && goto:pause
findstr /i "good well" Results.txt >nul && echo My day is doing good as well
:pause
pause
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, the string works perfectly, but I do not understand what `not.*good` and `not.*well` do, could you help me in explaining what they do or execute. Thanks

Comment: `not.*good` mean that answers like `not very good`, `not so good`, `I'm not feeling good` will be considered. The `.` is a wildcard for any character and the `*` is for repetition of zero or more occurrences of previous character or class...see `Using regular expressions with findstr` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx#ECAA